# Vuetify autocomplete - how to pass default value?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify autocomplete component and I want it to display a  default value in its input field

I tried to pass just value as prop and change v-model field to any string but it doesn't work - an input field is empty unless I choose value form the list

[Vuetify official example](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101)

```
<v-autocomplete
        v-model="select"
        :loading="loading"
        :items="items"
        :search-input.sync="search"
        cache-items
        class="mx-3"
        flat
        hide-no-data
        hide-details
        label="What state are you from?"
        solo-inverted
      ></v-autocomplete>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      search: null,
      select: 'Alabama',
      states: [
        'Alabama',
        'Alaska',
        'American Samoa',
        'Arizona',
        'Arkansas',
        'California',
        'Colorado',
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search (val) {
      val && val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    querySelections (v) {
      this.loading = true
      // Simulated ajax query
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.items = this.states.filter(e => {
          return (e || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((v || '').toLowerCase()) > -1
        })
        this.loading = false
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your CodePen is empty !

Comment: @Toodoo sorry
this example here https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/autocompletes#asynchronous-items

Comment: @Allan than you, looking at the code in that example allowed me to resolve my problem with this.

Comment: See if this helps - http://nimavat.me/blog/vuetify-autocomplete-default-value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this and what I did was passing to the v-model, the element at the 0 index position from the list:

```
:items="items"
v-model="items[0]"
```

Answer (score 11):

The `v-autocomplete` component will not display "Alabama" since "Alabama" is not found in `items`.  All you need to do is add "Alabama" to `items` to make it initially valid:

```
data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      items: ['Alabama'], // <- add the default here
      search: null,
      select: 'Alabama',
      states: [ ...
```

Comment: This works, but there's no reason to be "forced" to add such an item to the item list

Answer (score 5):

you can also use ***`auto-select-first`*** attribute along with default value in data.

```html
   <v-autocomplete
          v-model="selectedItem"
          auto-select-first
          :items="items">
   </v-autocomplete>
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['Default'],
      selectedItem: "Default",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem,
And finally figured it out
Use item-text and item-value to show the items
And init the v-model with the key
Of the item you want to display